# Why are the nobles so powerless against the Faith Militant?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

It doesn't seem to make sense at all. The Faith Militant are clearly far weaker than any of the Great Houses let alone the Tyrells and the Lannisters. They've only just gained a militia, have negligible training and their troops are armed with robes and clubs. Powerful religious leaders are just like any other rulers: they have to have a powerful army at their backs. Why would Tommen allow the High Sparrow to block his access to the Great Sep, imprison the Queen, or Cersei allow herself to be paraded naked through the streets? This is unprecedented historically as well.

Tommen could cancel his decree to arm them and bring charges of treason against the High Sparrow. It may be unpopular with many people, but surely the reputations loss from letting these indignities continue would be far more damaging to his rule. If the Crown can't even intimidate this rabble, they can forget about the Seven Kingdoms.

Comment: The Faith Militia is really popular with the peasants and common folk.  The city is recovering from war, and the absolute last thing they want is to have a peasant revolt on their hands.

Comment: the hold they have on kings landing is tenuous. peasants are a big pain to manage when they riot.

Comment: It was the same in Europe when the catholic church was most powerful. They crowned the kings and none dared to oppose them. Only King Henry VIII broke the bond and created his own version of Christianity with him at the head of the Church of England.

Comment: Because Cersei is an idiot. They never would have got that powerful if they had not been allowed to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons:

**The Faith Militant has the support of the common people.**

The *true* strength of the Faith Militant is that it derives its legitimacy from the Faith of the Seven. To a commoner that means that they are the earthly tools of The Seven themselves, a much higher authority than any king. The nobles know that if they mess with the Faith Militant they will come off looking like heretics. The Sparrows movement arose *because* the commoners were fed up with the war killing off the clergy. When Queen Cersei gave them permission to arm themselves they became the second coming of the Faith Militant. Answerable only to The Seven (through their earthly representative the High Septon). Dismantling the Faith Militant would be a *very* difficult task for any king. This *threat* issued by the High Sparrow in the TV adaptation sums it up nicely (emphasis mine):

> **High Sparrow:** "Have you ever sowed the field, Lady Olenna? Have you ever reaped the grain? Has anyone in House Tyrell? A lifetime of wealth and power has left you blind in one eye. **You are the few, we are the many. And when the many stop fearing the few..."**

**The Faith Militant has *history* behind it.**

This isn't the first time the Faith Militant have appeared in Westerosi history. When Aegon I conquered Westeros they were already a well established institution and a part of the Faith of the Seven. The Faith were reluctant to oppose Aegon, especially since he converted to the Faith of the Seven and declared himself to be its defender. This alliance ended when the Faith could no longer stomach the Targaryen custom of incestual marriage. The Faith Militant rebelled against the Targaryen in a war known as the Faith Militant Uprising. It was a long and bloody affair that claimed many lives on both sides, and only ended when King Jaehaerys I offered full amnesty in return for the Faith Militant disbanding.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that the reason lies in the civil war currently underway.

The Faith of the Seven has clearly become complacent, politically savvy, and to some degree corrupt. The Faith Militant, as a fundamentalist/reformist movement, is most likely doomed in the long run. As soon as the High Sparrow dies his successor is likely to be more manageable.

In the short run, the Faith Militant is vulnerable to applied force, since priests with clubs, no matter how faithful, are not a match for armed and armored knights and men at arms. The question is, how much uproar and chaos are the ruling class willing to endure?

In normal times the choice would be pretty clear, and the Faith Militant would be suppressed about the time they started seriously messing with the nobility. But. These are not normal times. Most obviously, a Kingslanding undergoing its own internal rebellion would be terribly vulnerable to attack by the anti-Lannister factions. At least one of them could be counted on to embrace the Faith Militant, at least to the extent of forming an alliance. Of course, in the aftermath of victory a ruthless victor would take advantage of the unsettled conditions to condemn the Faith Militant as heretic and wipe them out, then deal with the popular unrest in the traditional way.

Answer (score 1):

Reminding scene from series: Tommen stood near the Great Sept (s05e05), and Faith Militant refuses to let him to enter (because High Sparrow doesn't want to be disturbed while praying). Tommen heard voices from crowd: "bastard", "abomination". He realized that crowd supports Faith Militants. Also Tommen is shy, kind and indecisive.

It was mentioned in books that Cersei appointed idiots and indecisive persons to the Small Council - so none among them was too decisive and furious to attack Faith Militants.

Also you can see spoiler in the 6th season trailer:

> Jaime talk wit High Sparrow about spilling blood in the Great Sept. Also we see how "Sir Robert" attack Faith Militants. So, the battle between Faith and nobles began

P.S.  Also you can see examples in real history: Faith always was a real power. In the beginning of Game of Thrones it was strange that Faith's power is so weak

Comment: It's not strange that the Faith is so weak since King Jaegaerys "The Concilliator" disbanded the Faith Militant.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you can find historical precedents of an ascetic religious leader without a powerful army imprisoning the Queen or forcing the King's mother to do something as undignified as walking through the streets naked... The stuffing the small council with incompetents is a very good point btw.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle you can find some examples of conflicts between religious leaders and kings there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interdict . Also,the suitable example is ISIS - it was born in the war-torn country (like Westeros), their leaders don't show their richness, their weapons are not very modern,  they provide some "religious" ideas of purity and shows a lot of cruelty.

Another argument: if most of the king's army believe in The Seven, it's almost impossible to fight against Faith Militant - soldiers will have a choice: betray king or betray faith, and it's not obvious what to choose

Comment: @Schullz Faith was actually way too strong. had their own military orders as pointed out by Mooz. King Aenys and King Maegor had to fight bloody wars with the faith. It wasn't until King Jaehaerys convinced the exhausted clergymen to lay down their arms that the threat of the faith subsided.

Comment: @Aegon but my answer was only about the time when 1st season begins. Faith was not so strong that time.